# Easy way to fill up ResultSet with data

Tags: java, unit-testing, jdbc, mocking, resultset

I want to mock a ResultSet. Seriously.
I'm refactoring one big complicated piece of code which is parsing data from ResultSet, and I want my code to behave identically. So, I need to write a unit test for the piece being refactored to be able to test this.

After googling I came up with 2 ideas:

1. Use EasyMock, write looooong mocking sequence. VERY BAD solution: hard to add initial data, hard to change data, big test debugging promices.
2. Use Apache Derby or HSQLDB to create in-memory DB, fill it from file or String array, query with some magical InMemoryDBUtils.query(sql). Then use that ResultSet. Unfortunately, I did not find any magical InMemoryDBUtils to write the test fast :-). IBM article "Isolated unit testing of persistence with Derby" seems just fine about what I need, though...

Second approach looks somewhat easier and much more supportable.

What would you advice for creating such a mock? (despite doctors, of course :-)? Am I missing <strike>an eyebrow</strike> some silver bullet? Possibly, DBUnit is the tool for this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

DBUnit doesn't present a result set, to my knowledge, although it will well help you populate your in memory database.

I would say that a mocking framework is the wrong approach at this point. Mocking is about testing behavior and interaction, not just returning data, so it will likely get in your way.

I would instead either implement a result set interface, or create a dynamic proxy of a result set interface to a class that implements the methods you care about without having to implement the whole result set. You will likely find maintaining a class as easy as maintaining an in memory database (provided that the dataset under test is consistent), and probably easier to debug.

You could back up that class with DBUnit, where you take a snapshot of your result set with dbunit, and have dbunit read it back during the test from xml, and have your dummy result set read the data from dbunit's classes. This would be a reasonable approach if the data was mildly complex.

I would go for the in memory database if the classes were so coupled that they need to read data that was modified as part of the same test. Even then, I would consider using a copy of the real database until you managed to pull that dependency apart.

A simple proxy generation method:

```
private static class SimpleInvocationHandler implements InvocationHandler {
    private Object invokee;

    public SimpleInvocationHandler(Object invokee) {
        this.invokee = invokee;
    }

    public Object invoke(Object proxy, Method method, Object[] args)
            throws Throwable {
        method = invokee.getClass().getMethod(method.getName(), method.getParameterTypes());
        if (!method.isAccessible()) {
            method.setAccessible(true);
        }
        try {
            return method.invoke(invokee, args);
        } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
            throw e.getTargetException();
        }
    }
}

public static <T> T generateProxy(Object realObject, Class... interfaces) {
    return (T) Proxy.newProxyInstance(realObject.getClass().getClassLoader(), interfaces, new SimpleInvocationHandler(realObject));
}
```

Comment: Hello Yishai, thanks for feedback. I'll be mocking about 100 records for each of 10 or more tests, with record consisting of 10 fields. This, AFAIU, leaves me with DBUnit to store the data in file and custom ResultSet implementation. Thanks again for answering.

Comment: You are welcome. I would say that if each of the 10 tests requires different data, then yes, this would be a reasonable approach. With DBUnit you can take a ResultSet and write it to XML, so you just reference that in the test.

Answer (score 40):

I've had success with the MockResultSet class from here: http://mockrunner.sourceforge.net/. It allows you to create a class that implements the ResultSet interface, and lets you set the values for each column and row.

If your methods are working with ResultSets of reasonable size, you should be able to create tests that return the values you need fairly easily.

Here's a simple example:

```
MockResultSet rs = new MockResultSet("myMock");

rs.addColumn("columnA", new Integer[]{1});
rs.addColumn("columnB", new String[]{"Column B Value"});
rs.addColumn("columnC", new Double[]{2});

// make sure to move the cursor to the first row
try
{
  rs.next();
}
catch (SQLException sqle)
{
  fail("unable to move resultSet");
}

// process the result set
MyObject obj = processor.processResultSet(rs);

// run your tests using the ResultSet like you normally would
assertEquals(1, obj.getColumnAValue());
assertEquals("Column B Value", obj.getColumnBValue());
assertEquals(2.0d, obj.getColumnCValue());
```

Comment: Hello mjd79,

And thank you for your answer. The trouble in my case is that I'll defenitely have about 100 records for each testcase and about 10 testcases :-) Each record has 10 fields, including Dates, Numbers and Strings. Because of that, I'd prefer to store mock data in file, preferably in INSERT INTO form, which can be taken directly from almost every DB client.

MockRunner looks quite nice, but I'll keep it for some other case.

Thanks again for your time.

Comment: mockrunner was a great resource to mock out a simple result set for a batch job test. Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 8):

[Mockrunner](http://mockrunner.github.io/) can load a CSV or XML file and create a MockResultSet automatically.  It can also mock Connection and Statement, so all your JDBC stuff simply works, without even adding a JDBC driver to your classpath.

Answer (score 6):

I have written something for this same case. You can mock the resultset using Mockito. You can as well loop over the mock rows of resultset by mocking the resultset.next() with this piece of code.

```
// two dimensional array mocking the rows of database.
String[][] result = { { "column1", "column2" }, { "column1", "column2" } };

@InjectMocks
@Spy
private TestableClass testableClass;

@Mock
private Connection connection;

@Mock
private Statement statement;

@Mock
private ResultSet resultSet;

@BeforeTest
public void beforeTest() {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
}

@BeforeMethod
public void beforeMethod() throws SQLException {
    doAnswer(new Answer<Connection>() {
        public Connection answer(InvocationOnMock invocation)
                throws Throwable {
            return connection;

        }
    }).when(testableClass).getConnection();

    when(connection.createStatement()).thenReturn(statement);
    when(statement.executeQuery(anyString())).thenReturn(resultSet);
    final AtomicInteger idx = new AtomicInteger(0);
    final MockRow row = new MockRow();

    doAnswer(new Answer<Boolean>() {

        @Override
        public Boolean answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) throws Throwable {
            int index = idx.getAndIncrement();
            if (result.length > index) {
                String[] current = result[index];
                row.setCurrentRowData(current);
                return true;
            } else
                return false;

        }

        ;
    }).when(resultSet).next();

    doAnswer(new Answer<String>() {

        @Override
        public String answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) throws Throwable {
            Object[] args = invocation.getArguments();
            int idx = ((Integer) args[0]).intValue();
            return row.getColumn(idx);
        }

        ;
    }).when(resultSet).getString(anyInt());
}

static class MockRow {
    String[] rowData;

    public void setCurrentRowData(String[] rowData) {
        this.rowData = rowData;
    }

    public String getColumn(int idx) {
        return rowData[idx - 1];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If applicable, you could you take the result set you have now from your real data source, serialize it, and save the file.  Then you could deserialize that result set for each of your unit tests, and you should be good to go.

Comment: Hello GWLlosa, and thanks for your feedback too. I think DBUnit will help me with storing data in file.

Answer (score 1):

As long as you're not calling most of the `ResultSet` methods, I would probably just load a delimited text file into a two-dimensional array, and implement the methods I actually needed, leaving the rest to throw an `UnsupportedOperationException` (which is the default implementation for stubbed-out methods in my IDE).