# How to return Empty ResultSet

Tags: java, jdbc

I have the following code:

```
 private final ResultSet resultSet;

 public returnResult() {

   if(mycondition){
     resultSet = return Empty;
   }else
   resultSet = statement.executeQuery();

}
```

What's the correct way to return empty resultset without hitting db ?

Comment: What are you doing with the ResultSet? why is it not closed ? why don't you throw Exception?

Comment: Also see if the following answers help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2052745/how-to-programmatically-create-a-java-resultset-from-custom-data-with-no-databas

Comment: Also why ResultSet is final?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's actually quite complicated. You need a 'dummy' empty ResultSet class but this used to be almost impossible.

### History on JDBC

If the author of an interface adds new methods in some version upgrade, that means it is a backwards incompatible change: All implementations of that interface written before the version update are now no longer compilable, because they don't have an implementation of the newly added methods.

Normally, java does **not** break backwards compatibility.

Therefore, an interface defined in java core (in a `java.something` package) will never grow new methods, and therefore you could just mock it out, writing a suitable dummy implementation for each method inside it, QED.

Unfortunately, JDBC is one of the very few areas where **this does not hold** - the idea is that a select club of developers (DB vendors) will ever be writing implementations of the interfaces in the `java.sql` package, and therefore, assuming all db developers are on board, these interfaces CAN grow new methods.

And they did.

However, I believe, but I can't find any reference to this, that the JDBC team stopped doing this, instead relying on methods that are more or less pluggable, such as PreparedStatement's `.setObject(idx, value, targetSqlType)`.

With that background, here are your options:

### Make a dummy implementation normally

```
public class DummyResultSet implements java.sql.ResultSet {
   // an impl of every method here that returns a value
   // that fits the notion that it has no rows
}
```

It'll be pages and pages long as ResultSet has a boatload of methods. Unfortunate.

### Use Proxy

Proxy is a mechanism by which you can write a dynamic implementation of an interface: Instead of providing a method for each and every method in the interface, you just provide one single method: It is given the method name (as a string), and the parameters (as an object array). This way, you can write a big switch-on-strings block for all methods where you know you need to provide an actual sane result, such as ResultSet's `first()` (do nothing), or `close()` (do nothing), or `next()` (return `false`), and for anything else that flows in, you can just `throw SQLException`.

This conveniently also means that if the ResultSet interface ever grows more methods, your proxy-based dummy impl probably does the right thing for these new methods (specifically: throws SQLException):

```
private static final InvocationHandler dummyResultSetHandler =
  (proxy, method, args) -> {
    switch (method.getName()) {
    case "next":
    case "absolute":
        return false;
    case "afterLast":
    case "beforeFirst":
    case "close":
        return null;
    // you need way more of these, go through the entire list
    // of methods ResultSet has.
    default:
        throw new SQLException("No results");
  };

private static final ResultSet EMPTY_SET =
    java.lang.reflect.Proxy.newProxyInstance(
    ResultSet.class.getClassLoader(),
    new Class[] { ResultSet.class },
    dummyResultSetHandler);
```

### This is so complicated, isn't there an easy way?

Well, there is always running an actual query which guaranteed has no results:

```
SELECT 1 WHERE false
```

Will do the job in most DB engines: Gives you a guaranteed empty result set.

But it would cause a quick roundtrip to the DB engine, unfortunately.

### I want a simple solution that doesn't round trip

Then unfortunately you're out of luck. But what you can try to do is refactor your code somewhat. For example, you can instead return something else, such as a list of results, or an iterator, because 'empty iterator' and 'empty list' is easy to do.

In general the JDBC API is a bit.. low level for direct use. You can do it, of course, but there are abstractions built on top of JDBC that still give you all power of SQL that are so much nicer and would help here as well: JDBI and JOOQ are libraries you may want to investigate.

Comment: Your claim that interfaces besides JDBC in the core part of Java never get new methods is not correct. A good example is all the collection interfaces that got new methods in Java 8.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel You really think this answer would be improved with a completely irrelevant side-jaunt into the 'default' keyword? The point of an answer is to help the question-asker along the right path. Explaining the nuance that JDBC interfaces could grow new non-defaulted methods is relevant. Explaining the default keyword is not.

Comment: No, I think your answer can be improved by removing the unnecessary parts where you claim something never happens in Java, while it actually does. It adds nothing in my opinion, but could add unnecessary confusion.

Comment: JDBC is a special snowflake and that takes some explaining. I don't think this answer will be improved by trying to dance around that.

Comment: Fun fact about the default methods mentioned by @MarkRotteveel: it's incredibly hard to proxy default methods in a way that works on various JDKs.

Answer (score 1):

You could use jOOQ's [`MockResultSet`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org.jooq/org/jooq/tools/jdbc/MockResultSet.html) for that purpose, or roll your own taking inspiration from it.

```
if (mycondition) {

     // Result is the jOOQ representation of the JDBC ResultSet. You might not have to
     // create it with column information attached to it but your client code may expect
     // a ResultSet with N columns and corresponding data types, even if there's no data
     Result<?> result = DSL.using(DEFAULT).newResult(
         DSL.field("COL1", SQLDataType.INTEGER), 
         DSL.field("COL2", SQLDataType.VARCHAR(10))
     );

     resultSet = new MockResultSet(result);
}
else
     resultSet = statement.executeQuery();
```

Note that while jOOQ is dual-licensed for some use-cases, this case here can be done entirely with the ASL 2.0 licensed jOOQ Open Source Edition.

Disclaimer: I work for the company behind jOOQ.