# Manually create Resultset / CachedRowSet

Tags: java

I am developing an application where my app will get data from some other source in delimited format (raw data), then I need to convert the raw data to either resultset or cachedrowset, then I will pass the constructed resulset / cachedrowset to the client app (which calls my app to get data).

I've previously developed a `.Net` app which can achievethis by using `DataTable` (data constructed without connection).

However, I do not know how to achieve this in Java. Can anyone help?

Comment: Is your question about view technology? Which do you use?

Comment: Have you looked into this http://stackoverflow.com/q/878848/713414

Comment: @Tichodroma It is not a view technology, my app is just a middle man transmitting data to 3rd party app, and must in a form they (3rd party) understand or commonly used.

Comment: @KaipaMSarma, yup I did! It is kinda useful, but my app need stability & performance is my most top priority, especially processing very large data (100k++ with 100+ fields)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would create a `Model(POJO) class`, I will populate data from `resultset` to `model class object`. Convert it into json or xml. And send it as response to the Client application.

Java Object to xml conversion See : [What is the best way to convert a java object to xml with open source apis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/736343/what-is-the-best-way-to-convert-a-java-object-to-xml-with-open-source-apis)

Java Object to json conversion : Follow tutorial [here](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-do-convert-java-object-to-from-json-format-gson-api/).

Comment: This is nice, but will trouble my client who are going to use the data produced by me, either in xml or json format. But I will try to see what I can improve from here. Or maybe I should just use the SimpleResultSet way. :) Need some more testing and test case prove! as I need performance and stability :D